# Cannot write parquet using Spark (sparklyr) standalone mode Failed to rename DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr

I am using spark in standalone mode and accessing spark using sparklyr. I am trying to write to parquet files using the following code:

```
temp_parquet <- tempfile(fileext = ".parquet")

temp_parquet1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".parquet")

spark_write_parquet(train, temp_parquet)
```

However I constantly get the following error:

```
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus
 {path=file:/tmp/RtmpZbeJyA/file167e088fa054.parquet/_temporary/0/
 task_20171031030835_0010_m_000021/part-00021-9a9b102c-224e-445d-b704-
 7bddc915b2e7-c000.snappy.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=8468208; 
 replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1509419381000; 
 access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
```

I and using a Ubuntu VM with 128 cores and 2TB of memory. I changed the permissions for the directories and this does not seem to make any difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to run the spark-submit command with sudo ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by creating an hdfs cluster and writing the files as parquet to hdfs. Here is the code I used once the HDFS was up and running:

```
#Create unique paths to temp
temp_parquet <- tempfile(fileext = ".parquet")
temp_parquet1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".parquet")

#add hdfs to temp path
test_path<-paste0("hdfs://localhost:9000", temp_parquet)
train_path<-paste0("hdfs://localhost:9000", temp_parquet1)

#write parquet files
spark_write_parquet(spark_train_df, test_path, mode = "overwrite")
spark_write_parquet(spark_test_df, train_path, mode = "overwrite")
```